# How can i email invoice of payment to customer from stripe gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I have implemented `stripe gem` into my application. I want to send, Invoice and payment receipt to the customer through email.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation for emailing users in response to the `invoice.payment_succeeded` webhook: https://github.com/boucher/stripe-webhook-mailer

Comment: Thanks, Can we implement it other than Huroku application.

Answer (score 2):

Stripe has this covered in user settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this Railscasts episode? http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=asciicast

Comment: Thanks, But how can i email the invoice through web hook?